# Setuptools console_script entry point not found with install but it's found with develop

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point

[My package](https://bitbucket.org/fudepan/fbuildbot) has a entry point defined in it's setup.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='fbuildbot',
    version='0.1',
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'create = create:main',
        ],
    },
    install_requires=[
        "cookiecutter",
    ],
)
```

Thing is, If I do `python setup.py develop`, I can run the command just fine, but if I do install it with `python setup.py install` the install procedure runs correctly but the console script fails with `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matias/.venvs/fbuild/bin/create", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fbuildbot==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'create')()
  File "/home/matias/.venvs/fbuild/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/matias/.venvs/fbuild/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
  File "/home/matias/.venvs/fbuild/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
ImportError: No module named create
```

Clearly it's failing to setup the package correctly on the pythonpath. I thought it was because I have the script barely at the top level. So I tried adding wrapping it all in a package, moving all important parts to a inner module and changing the `setup.py` accordingly:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='fbuildbot',
    version='0.1',
    description="Buildbot configuration generator for fbuild",
    ...
    packages=['fbuildbot', ],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'create = fbuildbot.create:main',
        ],
    },
    install_requires=[
        "cookiecutter",
    ],
)
```

But it fails with the same message (with updated path, obviously).

Clearly I'm doing something wrong here. What could it be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in your packages argument. You only specify:

```
packages=['fbuildbot', ],
```

not

```
packages=['fbuildbot', 'fbuildbot.create'],
```

so your setup is not actually installing the "create" module. Makes sense that it could not be found.

I would recommend the find_packages utility

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'create = fbuildbot.create:main',
        ],
    },
    ...
)
```

which will handle all of it for you.